# Where are the `window.ethereum` docs?

Tags: ethereum

I'm calling `window.ethereum` and there are all these functions but it's confusing what they accept and the types. My understanding is that MetaMask injects something into window.ethereum... so I assume all the methods are from MetaMask? If so, are all the methods different for Coinbase wallet then?

1. Where are the docs for `window.ethereum`?
2. Are there any types associated with this?

My console when I `console.log(window.ethereum);`

```
coinbase - window.ethereum 
w {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 4, _maxListeners: undefined, _filterPolyfill: e.FilterPolyfill, _subscriptionManager: e.SubscriptionManager, …}
close: ƒ ()
enable: ƒ ()
genericRequest: ƒ ()
getChainId: ƒ ()
hasMadeFirstChainChangedEmission: false
isCoinbaseWallet: true
request: ƒ ()
scanQRCode: ƒ ()
send: ƒ ()
sendAsync: ƒ ()
setAppInfo: ƒ ()
setProviderInfo: ƒ ()
updateProviderInfo: ƒ ()
_addresses: ['0xmyAddress']
_eventListener: undefined
_events: {chainChanged: Array(2), accountsChanged: Array(2), connect: ƒ, message: ƒ}
_eventsCount: 4
_filterPolyfill: e.FilterPolyfill {logFilters: Map(0), blockFilters: Set(0), pendingTransactionFilters: Set(0), cursors: Map(0), timeouts: Map(0), …}
_jsonRpcUrlFromOpts: "https://mainnet-infura.wallet.coinbase.com"
_maxListeners: undefined
_overrideIsMetaMask: false
_relay: S {appName: 'localhost:3000', appLogoUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico', subscriptions: t, accountsCallback: ƒ, chainCallback: ƒ, …}
_relayEventManager: e.WalletSDKRelayEventManager {_nextRequestId: 0, callbacks: Map(0)}
_relayProvider: async ƒ I()
_send: ƒ ()
_sendAsync: ƒ ()
_setAddresses: ƒ ()
_storage: e.ScopedLocalStorage {scope: '-walletlink:https://www.walletlink.org'}
_subscriptionManager: e.SubscriptionManager {events: o, subscriptionMiddleware: ƒ}
chainId: (...)
connected: (...)
host: (...)
isChainOverridden: (...)
isMetaMask: (...)
isWalletLink: (...)
jsonRpcUrl: (...)
networkVersion: (...)
selectedAddress: (...)
[[Prototype]]: o
```

For example:

1. I can't find `setProviderInfo` in the [Ethereum docs](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/)
2. I can't find `setProviderInfo` in the [Metamask docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide) either
3. Just to show I'm not lazy... Coinbase wallet docs are [here](https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/wallet-sdk/docs/web3-react)

Answer (score 2):

`window.ethereum` is described in EIP-1193.

[EIP-1193 specification](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1193).

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful but I can't seem to find the methods there. Would you be able to provide some more context by any chance? Are these methods from Metamask, or are they somehow just undocumented, or should I be looking elsewhere? For example, the `setProviderInfo` method.

Comment: MetaMask is closed source software. Unfortunately you need to contact their customer support to ask for documentation.